# fckeditor's filemanager in codeigniter question

Tags: codeigniter, fckeditor, file-manager

I will be short in my question.

In my codeigniter setup I use database session. in this session I have a variable admin_site_id  which i get via

```
$this->session->userdata('admin_site_id');
```

What would be the best way to get the same thing in non CI php script?

I have a file manager of fckeditor, which I want to integrate but the pics should be uploaded in different folders , depending on the website administrator is editing right now...

Answer (score 1):

By default, CI stores session data in a cookie called ci_sessions, you can access it through: `$_COOKIE['ci_session'];`
Depending on if you magic_quotes turned on, encryption, or storing session data in the database you may have to remove slashes, unserialize the data, and run a SQL query to grab the data using the cookie hash.
You can read more on how to this here: 
 http://renownedmedia.com/blog/accessing-codeigniter-session-data-using-external-scripts

Comment: But I don't like the matter that I need to connect to DB again and from extra place....

Comment: True, although session->userdata() would be making a call back to the database anyway, I agree it sucks to have db settings in multiple places. You could require_once APPPATH.'/config/database.php'; in the script and access the CI db config from the script. Another option would be to turn off database session storage, or like @someoneinomaha suggested start using native php sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar on a CI project recently. I ended up using the Native Session Library (http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Native_session/) that uses native PHP sessions.

So I was able to set a session variable that was accessible in CI - using the typical CI session syntax, but was then able to access that same session using a non-CI php script.

My project for this isn't live yet, so I can't speak to any potential production issues that might come up, but others seem to be using it without problems.